# why cache: false is not working in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am using AJAX in my example. In this I used the `cache: false` property.
It always fires the request (I checked in network tab). Why is the request not cached? Here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGgKvd?editors=1010

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        alert('----')

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.github.com/events",
            data: {
                id: 123
            },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "json",
        }).done(function(json) {
            $("<h1>").text(json.title).appendTo("body");
            $("<div class=\"content\">").html(json.html).appendTo("body");
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
        }).always(function(xhr, status) {
            alert("The request is complete!");
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Well, `cache : false` turns of the caching, setting it to `true` would turn it on ?

Comment: You turned caching off... that's why caching is turned off

Comment: You should turn it on

Comment: it looks like jQuery implements this internally by simply appending a timestamp.

Comment: sill network showing new request ..please click on button and check network tab

Comment: It's always going to show a request, but in the network tab of the console it should says "from cache" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), If cache is set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

I guess you should change it to `true`

Comment: sill network showing new request ..please click on button and check network tab

Comment: In my Chrome, the second request shows `Status Code: 200 OK (from cache)` (Chrome/53)